# How do I debug a module made by Module::Starter?

Tags: perl, testing

I am practicing to make a new module using Module::Starter. I have written a few test cases for a package, and they run OK sometimes.

However I noticed there are two problems:

- When the test cases fail, I want put some print statements in the function being tested. I ran `make test` and it only tells me that my test cases failed, it does not show my printed output, despite that I am really sure that the print statements are reached.
- Say I have three test cases to test one function, I put a print statement inside the function, when the test cases run, it reports that only 1 out of the three test cases were run. If I remove the print statement, all three test cases will run. Why is that?

Here's my code:

```
# package declaration and stuff...
sub get_in {
  my ( $hash, @path ) = @_;
  my $ref = $hash;
  print 'lol'; # This is the troublesome print statement. Remove this statement and all three test cases will run and pass
  foreach (@path) {
    if ( ref($ref) eq 'HASH' && exists $ref->{$_} ) {
      $ref = $ref->{$_};
    } else {
      return undef;
    }
  }
  return $ref;
}
```

This is the test cases:

```
use Test::More tests => 3;
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
require_ok('Foo::Doc');
ok( Foo::Doc::get_in( { 'a' => { 'b' => { 'c' => 101 } } }, 'a', 'b', 'c' ) == 101 );
ok( @{ Foo::Doc::get_in( { 'a' => { 'b' => { 'c' => [ 1, 2, 3 ] } } }, 'a', 'b', 'c' ) } == @{ [ 1, 2, 3 ] } );
```

Comment: This question is not really specific to Module::Starter. The standard Perl project layout includes a `t` directory with `*.t` tests using Test::Simple or Test::More or some such to output test success or failure. Every Perl build toolkit provides tools to run your tests and output the results in the standard report using tools provided in Perl core.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few problems with you tests that need to be addressed as well as your question itself. First your question:

If you want output to show up in tests, you need to explicitly print to standard error. As a best practice, you also need your output prefaced with `#`. The [Test::More](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aMore) module provides tools you can use to do this easily.

```
my $got = Foo::Doc::get_in( { 'a' => { 'b' => { 'c' => 101 } } }, 'a', 'b', 'c' );
ok($got == 101); # you probably want is() instead, see below
diag("GOT $got"); # outputs "# GOT 101" or whatever to STDERR
```

If you don't want to print that output every time, but only when verbose logging is requested, you can use `note`:

```
note("GOT $got");
```

This is useful when you use `prove -v` to run your tests:

```
prove -l -v t/test.t
```

There's also an `explain` function that will dump out complex output for viewing:

```
diag explain $got;
# OR
note explain $got;
```

As for your other problems. It's generally preferable to use `is()` to `ok()`:

```
is($got, 101); # gives slightly more readable output on error
```

Also, when testing complex data structures you need to use `is_deeply()` to make a complete comparison:

```
is_deeply($got, [1, 2, 3]);
```

You should definitely take a look at the documentation of [Test::More](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aMore) because there's a great deal of useful information in there.

Answer (score 2):

To tackle your second question, you want to be careful writing to standard output in test scripts. `Test::More` scans standard output looking for telltale test output like `ok 5` and `not ok 6 - disgronificator enabled`. When you write `"lol"` to standard output but don't append a newline, the test module will set `"lolok 9 - it works"` and not recognize it as a test result. (For extra fun, put `print "not ";` statements before all your tests).

The better practice is like zostay says, to write to standard error, using `diag` and the other output functions that `Test::More` provides.